# Main Method of Excel 2010 Template

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, excel, excel-2010

I Have created an "Excel 2010 Template" in Visual Studio 2010 via right click on solution and add new project.

When I run my project, a new Excel document is openning. I want to find main method of this project. I couldnt find it. Whitout any main method, how can this project runs?

Answer (score 0):

In excel, you have to look at the events - there is no `main()` in Excel.

For opening a workbook, code in the **This Workbook** open event would execute when the spreadsheet is opened. ([KB Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/265113))

If you want to manipulate a worksheet from Visual Studio, then you would have to look at [these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet_events%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) methods:

- ActivateEvent
- BeforeDoubleClick
- BeforeRightClick
- BindingContextChanged
- Calculate
- Change
- Deactivate
- Disposed
- FollowHyperlink
- PivotTableAfterValueChange
- PivotTableBeforeAllocateChanges
- PivotTableBeforeCommitChanges
- PivotTableBeforeDiscardChanges
- PivotTableChangeSync
- PivotTableUpdate
- SelectionChange
- Shutdown
- Startup